# Error :Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1mjU.png)    public class countryController : Controller 
    //Error :Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: You're very unlikely to get any help without some code to debug. Please check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: The error-message is self-explanatory. *Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class*!

Comment: public ActionResult   //only used this kind of methods

Comment: Need some code snippet to look .Please provide the same

Answer (score 3):

You can't define an `extension method` inside a non-static class `countryController`

**This is not allowed:**

```
public class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SomeExtension(this String str)
    {

    }
}
```

**This is allowed:**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void SomeExtension(this String str)
    {

    }
}
```

You have a method whose first parameter starts with `this`, you need to find it and either modify it by removing the `this` or move it to a `static` helper class.

**According to C# Specifications:**

> 10.6.9 Extension methods
>
> When the first parameter of a method includes the `this` modifier, that
>   method is said to be an extension method. Extension methods can only
>   be declared in non-generic, non-nested static classes. The first
>   parameter of an extension method can have no modifiers other than
>   this, and the parameter type cannot be a pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

Add keyword static to class declaration:

// this is a non-generic static class

```
public static class yourclass
{
}
```

Following points need to be considered when creating an extension method:

> The class which defines an extension method must be non-generic,
>   static and non-nested

```
Every extension method must be a static method
```

> The first parameter of the extension method should use the this
>   keyword.

Comment: `static` controller in MVC ? I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: there is no static method in controller

Comment: my controller is not static

Comment: @user3185569 you are right. instance controller is instantiated once per request, multiple requests can be happening simultaneously. which is not good

Comment: @Rics The method doesn't have to be `static` to get this error, at least it has to have `this` before the first parameter. example : `public void MyMethod(this string str)`

Comment: error solved... thanks